# Prove if $f$ has a right inverse function: $f\circ g=id_x$ $\iff$ $f$ is onto $Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> We have the sets $X,Y$ and $f:X\to Y, \ g: Y\to X $
>
> Prove if $f$ has a right inverse function: $f\circ g=id_Y$ $\iff$ $f$ is onto $Y$ (surjective).

$\Leftarrow \forall y\in Y : \exists x\in X$ then $f(y)=x$ I need to show that $f\circ g(x)=x$ but I don't know how.

I have no clue on to start in the other direction.

BTW, I found below similar question but they're either not quite the same as this one or I didn't understand the answers:

[Left inverse iff injective; right inverse iff surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553186/left-inverse-iff-injective-right-inverse-iff-surjective)

Comment: For "$\Leftarrow$" you need to *choose* a preimage for every $y\in Y$, to do this you absolutely need the axiom of choice!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- For $\boxed{\Leftarrow}$: assume $f$ is surjective. Then, for all $y\in Y$ there exists $x_y\in X$ such that $f(x_y)=y$. Define $g\colon Y\to X$ to be the function which maps each $y\in Y$ to such $x\in X$ (if there is more than one $x$, then the function $g$ maps $y$ to one of them chosen in an arbitrary way. This excludes the possibility that $g$ map $y$ to two distinct values, in which case it wouldn't be a function). It follows that
  $$
  \forall y\in Y,\quad f\circ g(y) = f( g(y) ) = f(y_x) = y
  $$
  and $f\circ g=id_Y$.
- For $\boxed{\Rightarrow}$: assume $f\colon X\to Y,g\colon Y\to X$ are such that $f\circ g=id_Y$. Then for each $y\in Y$, $x_y\stackrel{\rm def}{=} g(y)\in X$ is a preimage of $y$ by $f$, as $f(x_y)=f\circ g(y) = id_Y(y)=y$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Why did you subtract the $idy(y)$ ?

Comment: Oh, it should be an $=$.

Comment: Please sir, can you elaborate first part: how you define $g$ ? What is definition of $g$?

Comment: "If there is more than one x, then the function g maps y to one of them chosen in an arbitrary way." Is there are more mathematically precise way to say this?

Comment: @SenZen Essentially, you want a [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function).

Comment: I know it's an old answer but in my opinion you should mention that to construct g you need Axiom of Choice and in fact this statement is equivalent to Axiom of Choice

Answer (score 4):

$\Leftarrow)$ For all $y\in Y$ there's $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ so define $g$ by
$$g\colon Y\rightarrow X,\quad y\mapsto x$$
and we have
$$f\circ g=id_Y$$

$\Rightarrow)$ Let $y\in Y$ so $f\circ g(y)=id_Y(y)=y$ so let $x=g(y)\in X$ hence we have
$$\exists x=g(y)\in X,\quad f(x)=y$$
so $f$ is onto.

Comment: It's all by definitions. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think your proof should emphasize the fact that if $g(y)$ has the possibility of being mapped to more than one $x \in X$, then one $x$ is chosen arbitrarily to guarantee that $g$ is well-defined (unambiguous).