# Understanding the proof: Surjectivity $\Leftrightarrow$ having right inverse

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I've been reading the answers in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790274/prove-if-f-has-a-right-inverse-function-f-circ-g-id-x-iff-f-is-onto-y) and trying to understand the proof:

I wrote down mine just to see if I understand it.

If $f : A \to B$ has a right inverse, then there exists a $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = id_B$. Let $a \in A$. Then  $f(g(a)) = id_B(a) = a$.

Suppose $f$ is surjective. Then for any $b$ in $B$ there's some $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Let $g(b) = a \in A$ if $b = f(a)$ and let $g(b) = s \in A$ if $b \not\in  B$. So, $g: B \to A$ is well-defined. Since $g(b) \in A, f(g(b)) = b$. So, $f \circ g(b) = b$ and $f \circ g = id_B$.

Does it make sense?

Comment: You can't define $g(b)=a$ until you've *picked* an $a$, because there could be more than one $a$ such that $f(a)=b$. The fact that you can "pick an $a$" in this way is a surprisingly complex proposition which can't be proven, and is thus an axiom (the Axiom of Choice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never showed that $f$ was surjective. A proof of such a claim would involve picking an arbitrary $b\in B$ but you do the opposite and pick $a\in A.$ And your statement $f(g(a))=id_B(a)$ does not follow (in fact if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then it's patently nonsense since $g$ only takes inputs from $B$). You are either confusing $A$ with $B$ or $f$ with $g.$

In the second part you also did not show that $g$ is well defined, you just stated it (and it's not true if $f$ is not invective). To make $g$ well defined you need to alter your definition so that you only pick one preimage of $b,$ but as it stands you don't specify that.

Comment: Let $b \in B$, then $f(g(b)) = id_B(b)$. Does it fix the first mistake you pointed out?

Comment: Yes. It would be clearer that you're showing surjectivity of $f$ if you said given this $b,$ set $a=g(b) \in A$ and note that $f(a) = b$ for the reason you have written there.

Comment: Let $g: B \to A$ as $g(b) = a$ for any $a \in A$. Would that work?