# Spivak's Calculus: Chapter 3 Problem 24b

Tags: functions, proof-writing, notation

24b) Suppose that $f$ is a function such that every number $b$ can be written $b = f(a)$ for some real number $a$. Prove that there is a function $g$ such that $f \circ g = I$

I think I do understand this question and how to solve it, but I'm struggling to find a way to express my solution in a mathematically rigorous way, particularly when $f$ is not injective. Here's my idea:

First of all, if $f$ is injective, then it's trivial.

Let $g(x) = a$, where $x = f(a)$ for any $a \in \text{domain}(f)$

Since $f$ is injective, by definition there is only one value of $a$ that satisfies $x = f(a)$ for each $x$, which means $g$ is well defined. And $\text{domain}(g) = \text{image}(f)$ (by definition of $g$), which from the supposition in the question is $\mathbb{R}$. Also, $\text{domain}(f) = \text{image}(g)$, since $f$ and $g$ are injective (but that fact is not important). So $f(g(x))$ is defined for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Finally, $f(g(x))$ = $f(a)$, where $x = f(a)$ for $x ∈ \mathbb{R} \to f(g(x)) = I(x)$.

But now if $f$ is not injective, it gets more complicated. If I keep my original definition of $g$, being "$g(x) = a$, where $x = f(a)$ for any $a \in \text{domain}(f)$", then that doesn't work because $g$ is no longer a function. Because since $f$ is not injective, there exists atleast 2 numbers $z$ and $w$ such that $z \neq w$ but $f(z) = f(w)$, which means there exists $x$ such that: $g(x) = z = w$.

I think the idea is to simply redefine $g$ to simply "choose" either $z$ or $w$, and assign it to $x$. For example it could choose the smaller of the two. The only difference this would make is now $\text{domain}(f) \subset \text{image}(g)$, instead of $\text{domain}(f) = \text{image}(g)$. But since that fact wasn't important before, the conclusion in the question still holds.

Here's my question. How do I explicitly write down a definition of $g$ that "chooses" the smaller of $z$ or $w$? Furthermore, recall there exists *at least* 2 numbers z and w. There could be arbitrarily more numbers such that $f(z) = f(w) = f(m) = f(n)$ and so on. And that's just one of the arbitrary branches the common values $f$ could take. There could be a different set of numbers $f(z_2)  = f(w_2) = f(m_2)$ and so on, that are not equal to $f(z)$, etc.

This is starting to get very messy. How can I express $g$ mathematically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove if $f$ has a right inverse function: $f\circ g=id_x$ $\iff$ $f$ is onto $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790274/prove-if-f-has-a-right-inverse-function-f-circ-g-id-x-iff-f-is-onto-y)

Comment: That question is the inversion of the question I am asking. My question is "If A, Prove B". That question is "If B, Prove A".

Comment: Actually, that question is “Prove that $A\iff B$”.

Comment: Oh yes my bad it is too. Unfortunately the top answer given relies on this sentence: "if there is more than one x, then the function g maps y to one of them chosen in an arbitrary way." How does one define an arbitrary mapping mathematically? That is exactly the question I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fallacy you noticed is real, well done for spotting it! What you are asked to show is basically the [axiom of choice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) for the real numbers. It is an axiom because you can’t prove (the general version) from the other axioms of set theory, even though it seems kind of sensible.

So you have two options:

- You can gloss over the fact that your definition has this problem and basically say: “Well, just choose any of the options, nothing strange to see here.”
- You can invoke the axiom of choice. It says (straight from the Wikipedia article): For any indexed family $(S_i)_{i\in I}$ of non-empty sets (where $I$ is some indexing set) there is a family $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $x_i \in S_i$ for every $i\in I$. I leave it to you to figure out how to get to Spivak’s claim. (Actually, my favorite formulation of the axiom of choice is basically what you have to prove, but not restricted to numbers.)

Comment: Thanks but I think in this case AoC is a bit overkill. I don't necessarily need $g$ to arbitrarily choose values from $range(f)$. For example I could define $g$ to always take the smallest value. The principle makes sense in my head, I just have no idea how to state it mathematically, and I'd like to know how.

Comment: Also I haven't studied any set theory at all yet, (just started with Calc I), so using AoC to solve my problem is not super convenient.

Comment: I think you need some version of choice. The “smallest number” might not exist. For example, $f$ might take the value $0$ at the $x$-values $1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots$ (and still be onto). According to the Wikipedia article, no explicit choice function for the reals is known.

Comment: And if the axiom of choice is not available, I fear you’re stuck with the first “solution”. Still, it’s good that you noticed the problem!

Comment: Ah yes that I did not think of, thanks.

Comment: Can you link the Wikipedia article please? Also if no explicit choice function for the reals is known, does that also mean no one has been able to prove there isn't one?

Comment: I linked the Wikipedia article above, but here it is again: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice. The claim about choice functions for the reals is at the end of the second paragraph. I’m not an expert on this matter, but: It has been shown that the general axiom of choice is independent from the other axioms of set theory, so it can’t be proved (unless set theory turns out to be inconsistent). I would interpret the claim in Wikipedia to mean that the question of choice functions for the reals is open, but both Wikipedia and my interpretation of it might be wrong.

Comment: (Also, as a side note: The problem in Spivak is even more specific, because (after translating it into a claim about indexed families of subsets) the indexing set $I$ has to be the reals (whereas in Wikipedia it can be any set). I don’t know whether this changes things but I don’t think so.)

Comment: I think I can prove an explicit choice function on the reals is impossible. Have a look at my proof below, let me know if it's right.

Comment: I think I accidentally proved ZFC is inconsistent help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists an explicit choice function $C :\mathcal P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. By definition, $C(A) = r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then clearly: $\{~~A \setminus C(A)~~\}$ $\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now define a function $A_n : \mathcal P(\mathbb R) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ recursively as follows:

$A_1(A)$ = $A$

$A_2(A)$ = $A_1(~~A_1 \setminus \{C(A_1)\}~~)$

$A_3(A)$ = $A_2(~~A_2 \setminus \{C(A_2)\}~~)$

etc. etc.

Formally:

1. $A_1(A)$ = $A$
2. If $A = \emptyset$, Then: $A_n(\emptyset) = \emptyset$
3. If $A \neq \emptyset$, Then:
   $A_n(A)$ = $A_{n-1}(~~A_{n-1} \setminus C(A_{n-1}~~)$ $~~~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 1$

Basically what I'm doing is applying the choice function $C$ to $A$ to choose a specific real number $r_1$ in $A$, then defining $A_2$ to be the set {$A$ missing $r_1$}, then applying $C$ to $A_2$ to choose a different real number $r_2$ in $A$, then defining $A_3$ to be the set {$A$ missing ($r_1$ and $r_2$)}, etc. etc.

Ok now define another function $Z:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ using the original choice function $C$ and the new $A_n$ function like so:

$Z(r)= \{n, ~where ~r=C(A_n)$

This function $Z$ is very special. Every element $r \in A$ corresponds to a unique value of $Z(r)$. In otherwords, $Z$ is capable of mapping every element of a subset of real numbers to a unique natural number $n$.

I feel like Cantor will have something to say about this...

Comment: But your functions $A_n$ won't recursively cover all the reals as the reals aren't countable.  "In otherwords, Cn is capable of mapping every element of a subset of real numbers"  Right, but *that* subset* is a countable subset, not an arbitrary subset.   Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Fleablood, this is a proof by contradiction. I'm saying if $A_n$ exist, then it DOES cover all the reals, even despite the fact that they uncountable. That's the contradiction, which proves the supposition at the start is false, I.e that there is no explicit choice function for every subset of real numbers. Please see my discussion with Eike Schulte in the comments of his answer above for context.

Comment: Actually now that you mention, doesn't this proof prove the axiom of choice is inconsistent with ZF (I.e ZFC is inconsistent)?? Oh no.

Comment: I must say that I don’t understand your argument. If I understand correctly, you first want to define a sequence of functions $A_n$. You claim that $A_n :  A \to A$ but I think what you mean is that $A_n$ maps non-empty subsets if the reals to non-empty subsets if the reals, by removing from its argument set the element chosen by the choice function $C$. Then you want to iterate this function. Here’s your first real problem: after removing one element, your set might no longer be non-empty, so your iteration will fail.

Comment: If you fix that part, I will take a look again. Now a couple of typographic remarks: You can get the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ by entering `\mathbb{R}` within math mode (i.e between two `$`s). You should always put the complete formula in one math environment. Because curly braces have a special meaning in math mode, you have to enter the braces for a set as `\{` and `\}` instead of `{` and `}`. Last (and most importantly), you should not use $\forall$ in front of the variable for set builder notation, i.e. write $\{x : \text{property of $x$}\}$ instead of $\{\forall x : \text{property of $x$}\}$

Comment: Yes, you're right, actually I should specify that the subset $A$ must not be finite, otherwise there certainly does exist a choice function on it. But if it's infinite then no matter how many times you remove an element, it won't be empty.

Comment: Sorry my notation sucks, I'm way out of my depth here. Was still fun though.

Comment: $A_n(A)$ only removes $n$ elements of $A$ and $\cap A_n$ only remove a contable number of $A$.  If $A$ was uncountable there are *still* an uncountable number left.  Your claim "Every element in A corresponds to a unique value of Cn(A)" is completely false because you are *not* associating each value of $A$ to a value of $Cn(A)$.  You are associating a *countable* number of $A$ to a unique value of Cn(A)$.

Comment: Fleablood, I disagree, but this comment chain isn't the place for extended discussion. Would you like to continue in chat?

Comment: Eike Schulte, I've edited the notation. Is it better? One thing I don't know how to do is express domain and codomain of the function $A_n$. I want $A_n$ to take subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as input and output subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I've only dealt with functions that take numbers as input like $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which means $f$ takes elements of $A$ and outputs elements of $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't want $A_n$ to take and give elements of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, I want it to take and give the actual subsets themselves.

Comment: Fleablood, in short, your argument comes down to $C_n$ is a "countable function", therefore it cannot map to an uncountable set, therefore it must be mapping to a countable set. This logic would be fine if $C_n$ was well defined, which it is not.

Comment: The set of all subsets og $\mathbb R$ is called the power set of $\mathbb R$ and is written (among other ways) as $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, so $A_n : \mathcal P(\mathbb R) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$. Your next problems: The functions $A_n$ don't quite do what you think they do. Let me write $R$ for the function that maps non-empty sets $A$ to $\{ x : x \in A \text{ and } x \neq C(A) \}$ (which can also be written $A \setminus \{C(A)\}$) and the empty set to itself. Your function $A_1$ is the identity and $A_n$ can be written as $A_n(A) = A_{n-1}(R(A_{n-1}(A)))$.

Comment: If you expand this for a few steps, you will notice that $A_n$ removes $2^n - 1$ elements, not just $n - 1$ as you claim below your definition. However, the bigger problem is that your definition of $C_n$ is unclear. What you get is one function $C_n$ for every natural number $n$, but you talk about them as if you only had one funtion $C_n$ (but if that is the case, why does it have a subscript?)

Comment: Eike Schulte, yes $C_n$ is very confusing. I've redefined it and renamed it $Z$. It should also make it clearer why $Z$ is one-to-one with $A$.

Comment: However after expanding, I am unable to see why $A_n$ removes $2^n - 1$ elements instead of $n-1$. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure: I think we agree that $A_1$ removes no elements and $A_2$ removes one, so let's look at $A_3$. When calculating $A_3(A)$, you first apply $A_2$ to get $A_2(A)$ which has one element less than $A$. Then you calculate $A_2(A) \setminus \{ C(A_2(A)) \}$ which removes another. Finally, you apply $A_2$ again, which removes a third element.

Comment: Now let's get to your real problem. You assume that your sequence will eventually hit every element of your subset $A$ but that isn't necessarily the case. For example, the choice function $C$ might always pick the smallest natural number in the set, provided there is one (and something else if there isn't). If you start with the set of integers, every set in your sequence $A_n(\mathbb Z)$ will still contain natural numbers (because at every point only finitely many have been removed). So $C(A_n(\mathbb Z))$ is always a natural number. In particular, $Z(-1)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Damn it fleablood was right.

Comment: Yeah you got me not gonna be able to escape that problem haha. Now that I've come this far, may as well give using AoC to solve my original problem a shot.

Comment: I'll put my answer in the original comment chain from your answer.

Comment: Can't fit my answer in a comment so I'll have to add another answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a non-injective function, $f$ can be written as $f = \{(x_1,f_1), (x_2,f_2)\cdots \} + \{(x_{1+i},f_i),(x_{2+i},f_i)\cdots \} + \{((x_{1+2i},f_{2i}),(x_{2+2i},f_{2i})\cdots \} + \cdots$ where $(x_{a+bi} = x_{c+di}) \implies (a+bi = c+di)$ and $(f_{a+bi} = f_{c+di}) \implies (a+bi = c+di)$.

Define $\hat f = \{(x_1,f_1), (x_2,f_2)\cdots \}$

Define $A_n = \{(x_{1+ni},f_{ni}),(x_{2+ni},f_{ni}) \cdots \}$

$\therefore f= \hat f + \sum_{p=1}^Z A_p$, where $Z \in \mathbb{N}$ or $Z = \infty$

Now using AoC: Construct a new set $\hat A$ which contains exactly one ordered pair $(x_{a+ni},f_{ni})$ from each $A_n$.

Define $f_{\text{injective}} = \hat f + \hat A$

Finally define $g(x) = a$, where $(a,x) \in f_{\text{injective}}$

Comment: Your argument is way to complicated. Here’s a hint: Consider the family $(A_i)_{i\in \mathbb R}$ given by $A_i = \{ x : f(x) = i \}$.