# Prove that $$ is injective and $$ is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

This is the question I got and I'm not sure how to approach it.

Let $f: A → B$ and $g: B → A$ be two functions, such that $g ∘ f(x) = x$ for all $a ∈ A$. Prove that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099699/left-inverse-in-f-a-iff-injective-proof) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790274/prove-if-f-has-a-right-inverse-function-f-circ-g-id-x-iff-f-is-onto-y?rq=1) answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $g$ surjective, pick any $a \in A$ and since $g(f(a)) = a$, let $b = f(a)\in B$ then $g(b) = a$ showing $g$ surjective. To show $f$ injective, if $f(x) = f(y)\implies x=g(f(x)) = g(f(y))=y\implies x = y$, hence $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ injective: If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then, applying $g$ yields $x_1=g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))=x_2$.

$g$ surjective: If $y\in A$, $g(f(y))=y$.